# with excel vba code, how can return the cell it's previous state when deleting seleted option in the cell?

Tags: excel, vba, undo

I have a simple concern about returning cell to its previous state (normally cell is including data validation list generated with DATA>DATA VALIDATION section) for a range of cells.

I have a macro which allows me to delete data validation list in the cell when selecting 'none' option from the dropdown list.

This is the code I am using.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cells As Range
    Dim DV As Range
    Dim isect2 As Range
    Dim valid As Validation
    Set DV = Range("K3:K28")
    Set isect2 = Intersect(Target, DV)
    Set valid = Selection.Validation
    If isect2 Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each Cells In isect2
            If Cells.Value = "None" Then
                Set valid = Selection.Validation
                Selection.Validation.Delete
            Else
                **Application.EnableEvents = False**
            End If
        Next Cells
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like to return the cell to its previous state (recovering same data validation list) when the selected option ('none') is deleted in the cell.

Edit

```vb
Sub Macro7(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Cells As Range
Dim DV As Range
Dim isect2 As Range
Dim valid As Validation

    Set DV = Range("K3:K28")
    Set isect2 = Intersect(Target, DV)
    
    Set valid = Selection.Validation
    If isect2 Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each Cells In isect2    
            If Cells.Value = "None" Then
        
                Set valid = Selection.Validation
                Selection.Validation.Delete
        
            ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells.Value) = True Then
        
                With Selection.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .***Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=sheet4!$A$2:$A$18"***        
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
        
            End If    
        Next Cells
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro while adding the data validation to a cell - that will give you the code you need.

Comment: Why do you need to delete the validation when that specific value is selected?  If you intend to re-apply the validation when "none" is deleted, then what purpose does the DV removal serve here?  If you don't remove the DV list, then your user can go back any time and select one of the other options.

Comment: my main goal is not to be able to select other options when 'none' is selected because the related range of cell is also a multi-select dropdownlist created by macro. I was trying to add code if/else but there are other multiple selected dropdown lists in the worksheet. I could not handle so.

Comment: I tried the recording macro method; however i encountered 'error numbered 1004' whenever i try to add it into whole code.

Comment: Please update your question to show what you tried, and tell us what error you got on which line.

Comment: But how does deleting the DV on the cell enable the other parts of your process?  It does nothing to the *value* of the cell...    Seems like you're adding complexity with no real gain.

Comment: There are other options beside 'none'. User can select more than one among other options because the range has multiple select dropdown list. In case they select 'none' the other options can not be selected. In advance i tried if/else command but all worksheet was hindered. Is there any possiblity to solve this problem with grouped data validation lists.

Comment: Actually i've thought about the possiblity to revert the macro back to the way it was before for this range when the active cell value is deleted

Comment: There is a Run-time error '"1004' for this line:  ***Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=sheet4!$A$2:$A$18"***

Comment: Maybe `With Cells.Validation` and not `With Selection.Validation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim c As Range, isect2 As Range
    
    Set isect2 = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("K3:K28"))
    
    If Not isect2 Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In isect2.Cells
            If c.Value = "None" Then
                c.Validation.Delete
            ElseIf IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
                With c.Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                         Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=sheet4!$A$2:$A$18"
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code you provided works like a charm.. Thank you very much for your effort and time.

Comment: The code alone works really great. However, it always gives run-time error 1004 for the same line if there are other codes (whatever code is; i tried all of them one by one). Could it be because I had to write this code as a sub macro with other codes?

Comment: It's difficult for me to know without seeing the other code.    If you rename it and call it from `Worksheet_Change`, passing in `Target` as a parameter, it should work the same way, but can't say for sure.